# How to find shortest path between two location and draw a zigzag path in iOS using GMSMapView?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am working on a google map application in which i have to create a path and get shortest path between 2 user entry location. i am able to get the lat, long val and able to draw a path also. but that path is line not a zigzag path. I share my screenshot what i faced and what my requirement.

My Requirement is:

[image]

But my output is:

[image]

And another requirement is I have to get so many route between that 2 places and which one is shortest path.

Please anybody can suggest me and give me some idea about that how can i implement.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use Google direction services:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

for ios:

github.com/ManoMarks/demos/tree/master/DirectionsAPIAsync

Comment: Its fine. But how can i get code for iOS its for Java only. right?

Comment: u said you working on google map application in ios.

Comment: Ya i am working on iOS , but what link u gave that is only for java

Comment: https://github.com/ManoMarks/demos/tree/master/DirectionsAPIAsync also y cant u use google direction api as a web service to get route.